# Control content access based on field value in user profile?

Tags: 7, views, rules, users

I have two specific user types on my website: "Manager" and "Employee". I will have ten managers and 100 employees. Each Manager will manage 10 employees.

Employees will have permissions to create "Content Type A" nodes. I want their managers to be able to edit/view only those "Content Type A" nodes that were created by their employees.

I created a User Reference field in the profile form. that UR field is populated only with the names of the Managers. When a new employee is registered their manager's name will be selected from that UR field.

I feel like I should be able to control each Manager's access to Employee-created content based on that UR value in each employee's profile, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to accomplish that. Would Views be the best bet, or would I need to develop a custom permissions module that compares the logged-in Manager's UID with the UID related to the Manager selected in the UR field on the employee profile? Or perhaps some kind of Rules setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module seems to be the answer:

> - **User Relationship Node Access** lets users control access to their content based on relationships

Comment: thanks for your input. It appears that the User Relationships module may be just what I am looking for. I will post back here with my method if it does indeed work out. Thanks!